# Unicode characters are missing in NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I have an `NSString` which contains unicode characters itself.

Ex:

```
It's blank.\u000e test \u000f
```

The `NSString`'s length is `19`.

Here, `\u000e` and `\u000f` are Unicode characters.

I convert the above mentioned `NSString` to an `NSMutableAttributedString` and I have applied some font-weight properties. Then, I have logged the `NSMutableAttributedString` and get the following output.

My Sample Code:

```
NSString *contAtRng = @"It's blank.\u000e test \u000f";
NSMutableAttributedString *attrText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:contAtRng];
NSMutableDictionary *attrs = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[attrs setObject:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:10] forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
[attrText setAttributes:attrs range:NSMakerange(0,contAtRng.length)];
NSLog(@"String : %@",attrText);
```

Output:

```
It's blank. test {
NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x16d22250> font-family: \"Helvetica Neue\"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 10.00pt";}
```

The `NSMutableAttributedString` length is `17`, now.

In the result, Unicode characters are missing. I don't know what I did wrong with my code.

Comment: Do the characters `0x000e` and `0x000f` have glyphs?  They appear to be control characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are trying to create `NSMutableAttributedString` with some specific font family (Ex: `HelveticaNeue-Bold`) which contains some unicode characters, It will replace the unicode character with empty string and provide the remaining string.

So, We'll miss the unicode characters.

To avoid this problem, **Skip the unicode characters** while setting font family for the `NSMutableAttributedString`

**Here is my code:**

```
NSString *contAtRng = @"It's blank.\u000e test \u000f";
NSMutableAttributedString *attrText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:contAtRng];
NSMutableDictionary *attrs = [NSMutableDictionary new];  
[attrs setObject:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:10] forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
[attrText setAttributes:attrs range:NSMakerange(0,11)];
[attrText setAttributes:attrs range:NSMakerange(12,6)];
NSLog(@"String : %@",attrText);
```